# $L^{\infty}$ estimate on the boundary by means of Sobolev norms in the interior

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, inverse-problems

I am studying this paper http://143.248.27.21/mathnet/paper_file/washington/gunther/cpde.pdf
and I have a doubt I have not been able to solve since yesterday. In page 14, just before the last bunch of equations, they say:

> The estimate $\Vert \psi_{q} \Vert _{C(\partial \Omega)} \leq C \tau
> > ^{1/4},$ which follows by (0.3) and Sobolev embedding theorem...

(0.3) tells us that for any $0\leq s\leq 2,$ we have
$$\Vert \psi_{q} \Vert_{H^{s}(\Omega)}\leq C\tau^{s-1}.$$

I am incapable to derive the mentioned estimate. I will share with you what I have tried, but you may stop reading from here if you already know an answer.

By Sobolev embedding, we may write
$$\Vert \psi_{q} \Vert _{C(\partial \Omega)} \leq C \Vert \psi_{q} \Vert_{H^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)} $$

Now, by the trace theorem, we can bound this last quantity by:

$$C^{\prime} \Vert \psi_{q} \Vert_{H^{\frac{n+1}{2}}(\Omega)}$$

and I don't know what to do from here. Another try was to use logarithmic convexity of Sobolev norms, but if you write the details you will see that everything thus obtained is as useless...

**Another question, independent of what is above** I also don't know how to derive the estimate (0.3) for the Complex Geometrical Optics. I know how to do this in the construction for the problem with complete data, by using Fourier series. I am not sure whether this automatically applies here (you can see they do not prove (0.3) anywhere in the paper)

Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: If you look at the paper they cite just before stating 0.3 http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971291?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents, I think they're referencing the construction in Thm 1.1 in that paper, and notice that in there they do have $s>n/2$ which is what you need.

Comment: Well, maybe it's better if you, instead of applying the trace theorem with a full derivative, apply the trace theorem with half derivative:
$$
\|u\|_{H^s(\partial \Omega)}\leq C\|u\|_{H^{s+0.5}(\Omega)}.
$$
Does this help?

Comment: jajajaja ouch, my bad. No, no, that was what I said. It's just that for some reason I though that you were using the Evans version of the Theorem with a full derivative. I'm sorry for the confusion.